# Should website & API have a different hostnames?

Tags: api

The webapp I'm making is medium-sized, and it's going to be a single-page static JS+HTML app (made with Backbone, and served by nginx) which accesses an API, hosted on a proper webserver.

Should the API be under a different hostname, or same hostname but different path? What could be possible pros & cons of these options? Both options are feasible, thanks to nginx.

Comment: How does an app access an `API`? You use an `API` to allow interaction with your app... I'm not sure how to read your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, what I meant is: the static parts (HTML & JS & Backbone.js) will be calling AJAX queries to the API. That's how "the app will access the API"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I kind of had an idea since @TVK was able to answer your question. I just felt that it could have been clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an intuitive separated environment. Splitting the access location like `example.com` and `api.example.com` allow the hostnames to describe the purpose of each environment. Separating these keeps things organised and clear while using the same hostname for each could cause confusion as to what kind of request is being done.

Using `example.com/api` is possible as well, but could lead to future issues where directories are used for other things as well. E.g., would `example.com/newfeature` have a directory like `example.com/newfeature/api` as well?

In the end, it's all a matter of personal preference though. Pick something that works in a clear way for your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is somewhat irrelevant, as long as your code is flexible about the base url of the api.  Make sure you can configure your code (both javascript and back-end) so that all api URLs are relative to some single configuration parameter and you will have flexibility to put your api service anywhere you want or need to put it.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to think it might be a good idea to have everything on the same hostname, because the user might have disabled 3rd party cookies, and so the API server won't be able to recognize you after you close your browser. Before anyone tells me I should have the main website serve the cookies instead, let me tell you that I'd like the main website to be completely static HTML/JS files, and so they have no ability to serve httpOnly cookies, which is the kind of cookies I like.

Comment: Another reason to avoid separate hostnames, is to avoid the CORS pre-flight OPTIONS request that happens before API requests. If every API request has a different URL endpoint, then the pre-flight requests will make the web application considerably slower.